# Scroll-to-top button won't appear

Tags: javascript

Hej there,

I'm not a developer, but trying to set up a small private webpage for my wedding celebration, and want to add a scroll-to-top button. I am programming the website manually using VSC. My problem is that I can generate the button allright using HTML and CSS, but the JS doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea what's wrong. Yes, JS is enabled in the browser.

So I add this button in HTML:

`<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>`

and link my .js file in the HTML page header with

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"> </script>`

Then I add the CSS:

```
#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

When I set the display property to "block", the button shows where it's supposed to be. The hover effect also works fine.

Then I added the .js file; I actually just copy-and-pasted code from W3Schools. When it didn't work, I tried to fiddle around with it, but found no solution.

The button is supposed to appear when the page is scrolled down 20px, and disappear when it's less. However, the button just never appears no matter how far I scroll the page.

```
//Get the button:
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

It'd be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `<button>` element inside the `<body>` element and gave height to the `<body>` element so that the `onscroll` event could be triggered. In this case the `<button>` works fine when the `onscroll` event is triggered. The scrollbar must be opened for the `onscroll` event to be triggered. The page `height` must be greater than the full screen height for the scrollbar to open.

```js
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function scrollFunction() {
  console.log(document.body.scrollTop )
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) 
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  else 
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
}

scrollFunction();
```

```css
body{
  height: 804px;
}

#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Hej there, thanks for the tip, however the body is considerable higher than 1,000 px (which is why I need the button in the first place), and the scroll bar shows all the time). So this doesn't help, unfortunately, the result is the same.

Comment: @Bleiboy I assigned that value as an example. The content on the page must exceed the maximum browser height for the scrollbar to open. The "TOP" button will come in handy then.

Comment: @Bleiboy In the question, you said that the "TOP" button is not visible even though I scrolled the page, I told you why this problem was caused. The "TOP" button is displayed when the page height is greater than 784px and the bottom area is moved. The purpose of the "TOP" button is to get to the top of the page. All the issues you mentioned have been resolved. I still don't understand what you want to ask.

Comment: Hej Sercan, maybe I should have mentioned that I actually tried your solution, but it still didn't work. The scrollbar shows all the time, too. However, I got this now (see my answer).

Comment: @Bleiboy In the question, you stated that you defined the scripts in the **javascript.js** file that you defined within the `<script>` element.